# Сохранение состояния кнопки при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При добавлении товаров в корзину обновляется состояние кнопки на зеленую, но когда обновляю страницу, товар остаётся в корзине и в бд, но кнопка откатывается в начальное состояние (становится серой). Как мне сделать при обновлении страницы синхронизацию состояния кнопки с товаром в корзине?

Код с проверкой состояния кнопки ниже:

```
return (
<div className="card">
  <img src={imageUrl} width="150" height="auto" alt="" />
  <h5>{title}</h5>
  <div className="cardAdd">
    <div className="cardPrice">
      <span>Price: </span>
      <b>{price}</b>
    </div>
    {onPlus && (
      <img
        className="plus"
        onClick={onClickPlus}
        width={20}
        height={20}
        src={isAdded ? "/images/btn-checked.svg" : "/images/add.svg"}
        alt="Add to cart"
      />
    )}

    <div className="favorite" onClick={onClickFavorite}>
      <img
        src={isFavorite ? "/images/like.png" : "/images/unliked.png"}
        alt="Add to favorite"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
```

Здесь товар в корзине связан с бд:

```
useEffect(() => {
async function fetchData() {
  const cartResponse = await axios.get("https://6257c564e4e0b7314280074d.mockapi.io/cart");

  setCartItems(cartResponse.data);

}

fetchData();
}, []);
```

Ниже скрины проблемы:

Товар в корзине и кнопка зеленая:
[image: Товар в корзине и кнопка зеленая]

Страница обновлена, товар в корзине, кнопка серая:
[image: Обновлена страница]

Comment: Нужен полный код где видно куда устанавливаются данные из корзины cartItems, нужно посмотреть откуда берется isAdded.

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужен весь код, но можно немного по-другому добавив в src еще одну проверку.
cartItems это то что у тебя лежит в корзине.

src={isFavorite || cartItems.length > 0 ? "/images/like.png" : "/images/unliked.png"}

Comment: Звучит просто и привлекательно, сегодня вечером попробую